# I want to switch from app to chrome web browser and then navigate back to same app in appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

```
public class switching {

    @Test
    public void openBrowser() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability("deviceName","One plus 5");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "9a0f2cfd");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformversion", "9.0.11");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "io.appium.android.apis");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos");
        URL url =new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        AndroidDriver driver= new AndroidDriver(url,cap);
        // after performing actions on app want to navigate to web browser

  }
}
```

Now, I want to navigate to chrome browser and open any url and then navigate back to same app

Comment: this might be of help https://appiumpro.com/editions/4-using-appium-for-testing-mobile-web-apps

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

- You may use `driver.activateApp("com.android.chrome")` to open Mobile Chrome. However, in this case, you need to handle the URL opening manually (locate URL input field, type it, etc.)
- You may use `adb` command to open Chrome on a particular page, e.g:

```java
public void openChromeNavigatedTo(String URL) throws IOException {
   String command = String.format("adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d '%s'", URL);
   Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
}
```

When the Chrome opened, you may consider it as a usual mobile application: find locators and interact with them.

Once you've done, you may want to close Chrome:

```java
public void closeChrome() {
   driver.terminateApp("com.android.chrome");
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no guarantee, that after that your main app became in focus, so you should do this explicitly:

```java
public void launchApp() {
   driver.launchApp();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Native App/Hybrid App + Mobile Chrome Browser Switching

```
String appPackage = "com.android.chrome";
String appActivity = "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"; // OR // org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity

//Wait until launch chrome browser OR other browser
Activity activity = new Activity(appPackage,appActivity);
activity.setAppWaitPackage(appPackage);
activity.setAppWaitActivity(appActivity);

switchContextBasedOnString("WEBVIEW_chrome");
new WebDriverWait(androidDriver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Test1"))).click();

switchContextBasedOnString("Native");
```